# Task ActivityDate - Behaviour in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, date, tasks, fields, apexinputfield

For a number of apex:inputfields in Visualforce, I'm suppressing the Salesforce date picker and using the browser based one. I'm experiencing odd behaviour when attempting to do so on the Task ActivityDate field:

Example

Markup:

```
    <apex:page controller="TestController" docType="html-5.0">
        <apex:form id="theForm">
            <apex:inputField value="{!t.ActivityDate}" showDatePicker="false" type="date"/>
        </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public Task t{get; set;}
}
```

When trying to compile the VF code, I get the following error:

```
Expected input type 'datetime-local', got 'date' for Date data type
```

I don't get this error for other Date fields in the database, which have all worked fine. I've also checked the DisplayType for the field and is definitely is being returned as a Date field like all the others.

**Out of interest, I gave the compiler what it wanted and changed the type to "Datetime-local" and it saved fine. However, running the page produced an Internal Server error.**

Has anybody else run across this issue and resolved it? Or is the answer to create a controller variable to proxy for the ActivityDate field?

Comment: Can you post a more complete MVR? One complete, minimal page that can be copied into any org to reproduce the issue will get you an answer more quickly.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Certainly. I've edited to update.

Comment: I'm intentionally suppressing the datepicker in favour of the browser specific options in this use case.

Comment: Ah, I follow. Have you considered javascript alternatives such as jquery's datepicker?

Comment: I'm attempting to build a generic component into which I can put any field as an attribute. For simplicity, I'm hoping it can rely on the browser based options (so it works in mobile, etc, without too much work). In this instance, I'm having to not use the generic component, but I suppose I'm now interested in the inner workings of Salesforce as to why this field doesn't play like the others.

Comment: I actually did not get an internal server error when using `type="datetime-local"`.

Comment: Like Adrian, I also had no problems with that method.

Comment: The example you've used to update the question is subtly different to my original. When only using Standard Controller, the error doesn't appear. It only shows up when using the Controller, rather than standard controller.

Comment: You've found a bug (gack id: 374252212). You should open a case with developer support.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the input type dynamically through JavaScript. I tried with the below approach and it is working in Chrome. As the input field is html date type it should work in mobile devices too.

```
<apex:page controller="TestController1" docType="html-5.0" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function stringToDate(_date,_format,_delimiter){
            var formatLowerCase=_format.toLowerCase();
            var formatItems=formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
            var dateItems=_date.split(_delimiter);
            var monthIndex=formatItems.indexOf("mm");
            var dayIndex=formatItems.indexOf("dd");
            var yearIndex=formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
            var month=parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
            month-=1;
            var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex],month,dateItems[dayIndex]);
            return formatedDate;
         }
    </script>    
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:inputField showDatePicker="false" value="{!t.ActivityDate}" id="activityDate" style="width:110px"  />            
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
        var elem = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.activityDate}');
        var mydate = stringToDate(elem.value,"dd/mm/yyyy","/").toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        elem.value = '';
        elem.type = 'date';
        elem.value = mydate;
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found this produced an error on save. I also found a simpler approach that worked for me in the near-term. I will update an answer here accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I made use of a "dummy" property in the controller to represent the date and an  field:

```
<apex:input value="{!activity.aDate}" id="ActivityDateField" styleClass="form-control" type="date"/>
```

I then used the getters and setters of the property to ensure they were aligned with the ActivityDate on the Task record. Not the most elegant solution, but worked for my purposes.